# Cell content overlaps when TableView Scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i scroll the tableview up and down the content in the cells gets overlapped, Why is this and how can i correct it ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NS

IndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

        }

            UITextField* tf = nil ;

                switch ( indexPath.row ) {

                    case 0: {

                        cell.textLabel.text = @"First Name" ;

                        tf = firstNameTextField = [self makeTextField:self. placeholder:@"F name"];

                        [cell.contentView addSubview:firstNameTextField];

                        break ;

                    }

                    case 1: {

                        cell.textLabel.text = @"Last Name" ;

                        tf = lastNameTextField = [self makeTextField:self.lastName placeholder:@"L name"];

                        [cell.contentView addSubview:lastNameTextField];

                        break ;

                    }

                    case 2: {

                        cell.textLabel.text = @"age" ;

                        tf = agetextfield = [self makeTextField:self.password placeholder:@"Age"];

                        [cell.contentView addSubview:agetextfield];


                        break ;

                    }


                }
                return cell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells were reused in this case. So the cells are overlapped on others. Just modify your code to resolve this.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        UITextField* tf = nil ;
        for(UIView *view in [cell subViews]){

            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextFiel class]]){

                  [view removeFromSuperView];
                 }
        }
            switch ( indexPath.row ) {

                case 0: {

                    cell.textLabel.text = @"First Name" ;

                    tf = firstNameTextField = [self makeTextField:self. placeholder:@"F name"];

                    [cell.contentView addSubview:firstNameTextField];

                    break ;

                }

                case 1: {

                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Last Name" ;

                    tf = lastNameTextField = [self makeTextField:self.lastName placeholder:@"L name"];

                    [cell.contentView addSubview:lastNameTextField];

                    break ;

                }

                case 2: {

                    cell.textLabel.text = @"age" ;

                    tf = agetextfield = [self makeTextField:self.password placeholder:@"Age"];

                    [cell.contentView addSubview:agetextfield];


                    break ;

                }


            }
    }


            return cell;
```

Comment: No change, still i get the same result.

Comment: Did you try cell.contentView = lastNameTextField

Comment: and change style to UITableViewCellStyleDefault

Comment: Yes, i did. The cell.textLabel.text isn't getting overlapped. It's only the TextFields that are getting overlapped. Any clue ?

Comment: When i scroll down, the value of the textfield in the first cell, gets displayed in the last row of the tableview.  :( Help

Comment: see this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html  u can find out way to create custom table view cell

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an `UITextField` to a cell every time cell is reused.
The idea is to add it only when the cell is created and then get an existing view from an existing cell

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  UITextField* tf = ...;
  tf.tag = kMyTextFieldTag;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:tf];
}
UITextField* tf = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kMyTextFieldTag];
tf.text = ...;
```

Even better idea is to make the `UITextField` an `accessoryView` of the cell instead of adding it as a subview.
If it does not produce a desired result, consider making a custom cell instead of adding views to `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, except that you never remove the 'old' subviews from the cell's contentview. So add this code before `UITextField *tF = nil;`:

```
for(UIView *v in cell.contentView.subviews){
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Just before "UITextField *tF = nil;"

Comment: When i do the above, and scroll down, the value of the first textfield gets displayed in the last row.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add all subviews (label etc) to your cell.contentview only one time , means you can modifiy your cellForRowAtIndexPath methods as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

UITextField* tf = nil ;

            switch ( indexPath.row ) {

                case 0: {

                    cell.textLabel.text = @"First Name" ;

                    tf = firstNameTextField = [self makeTextField:self. placeholder:@"F name"];

                    [cell.contentView addSubview:firstNameTextField];

                    break ;

                }

                case 1: {

                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Last Name" ;

                    tf = lastNameTextField = [self makeTextField:self.lastName placeholder:@"L name"];

                    [cell.contentView addSubview:lastNameTextField];

                    break ;

                }

                case 2: {

                    cell.textLabel.text = @"age" ;

                    tf = agetextfield = [self makeTextField:self.password placeholder:@"Age"];

                    [cell.contentView addSubview:agetextfield];


                    break ;

                }

    }





            return cell;
}
```

You dont need to add and remove subviews from your cell each time cell is reloaded.